# urgent help fatal error magento 2 website is working but all the styles are gone after running command

Tags: magento2.2, fatal-error, command-line, ssh

need serious and urgent help.
i was trying to disable a module in magento2.2 by command line.
first i run the command: `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

and after that i ran the command to disable the module : `php bin/magento module:disable My-ModuleName`

after doing that when i went ot my website and dashboard it was all like the following screen shot 
[image]

i tried to clear cache but nothing is working. can someone please help me!!!

Comment: Open browser console. Check which errors is there. Write it here.

Comment: how to open browser console?

Comment: Add more info, what do you use at the server side. Os, server, which index file do you use (index.php or pub/index.php)

Comment: hit f12 at the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: you'd run that every time you run setup:upgrade

Comment: I am getting fatal error during add product from backend manually https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/318269/57334 any help thanks @Raul Sanchez